# Save local file in Flash Projector using FileReference?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, filereference, projector

I'm making a Flash projector which will be distributed on CD. I want to allow people to copy files off of the CD. Is this possible? Should I be using FileReference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you target Flash Player 10 (Public Settings [Ctrl+Alt+F2] -> Flash -> Player), you can use the FileReference.save() method.

The old method was to upload it to a server and use FileReference.download(), but this is not needed anymore (unless you need FP9 compability).

Here's a quick and simple tutorial on how to use it:
http://blog.everythingflex.com/2008/10/01/filereferencesave-in-flash-player-10/